# Land masking in ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, masking

I'm trying to mask land in a raster and just wondering if anyone knows how to do this. I tried using the raster calculator by producing a new raster based on a threshold value but my output raster is classified to 0 and 1 - 0 being my mask. I still want to retain the original values in my pixel.

Answer (score 1):

```
Con("RasterName", 0, "RasterName", "value= Number")
```

this algorithm should take care of that. For the certain "number" raster is converted to "0" rest of it will be kept as "RasterName" if you have more complex algorithm you need to nest another Con in this Con.